# Define Boolean operations in terms of inclusive denial

Tags: boolean-algebra

Define the binary operation of *inclusive denial*, denoted by $|$ on a Boolean algebra making $x|y = x' \vee y'$.

Show that the binary operations of disjunction $\vee$, conjunction $\wedge$, the unary complement $'$ and the nullary constants $0$ and $1$ are definable from $|$ alone.

I could conclude that $x' = x' \vee x' = x|x$, but what about the others? Perhaps I'm missing some extra hypothesis?

Comment: $x\land y=(x\mid y)'.$

Comment: And you should know that all the others are definable from $'$ and $\land.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0. Let $x|y = x' \vee y'$.
1. Unary complement $':\quad x' = x' \vee x' = x|x$
2. Disjunction $\vee:\quad x \vee y = (x'|y')=(x|x)|(y|y)$
3. Conjunction $\wedge:\quad x \wedge y = (x'\vee y')'=\bigl[(x'|x')|(y'|y')\bigr]'=(x|y)'=(x|y)|(x|y)$
4. Constant $0:\quad0 = x\wedge x'=(x|x')|(x|x')=\bigl[x|(x|x)\bigr]\Bigl\lvert\bigl[x|(x|x)\bigr]$
5. Constant $1:\quad 1=x\vee x'= x'' \vee x' = x' \mid x = (x \mid x) \mid x$

My thanks go to @amrsa for pointing out a simplification for the constant $1$.

Comment: A shorter version for 5 is: $$1 = x'' \vee x' = x' \mid x = (x \mid x) \mid x$$ and then reach the same conclusion as you did for the constant $0$ by using $0 = 1'$.